# Transporting ranges of values that are not in the same line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this code bit where it gets some ranges and the get the values inside them, one by one. I've tried to use GetRangeList to shorten it, but i had issues using SetValues along it because they turned out to be a string. The code actually works, it does everything it needs to do, but i'm trying to optmize it. Is there any way?
I've also tried to specify the range as a matrix, like "E12:G15", but then it doesn't transpose to a whole line, it reads it as equal to the source.

```
  var dados1 = origem.getRange("E12:G12");
  var source1 = dados1.getValues();
  var dados2 = origem.getRange("E13:G13");
  var source2 = dados2.getValues();
  var dados3 = origem.getRange("E14:G14");
  var source3 = dados3.getValues();
  var dados4 = origem.getRange("E15:G15");
  var source4 = dados4.getValues();
  sheetBase.getRange(sheetBase.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 3).setValues(sourceEqpt);
  sheetBase.getRange(sheetBase.getLastRow(), 4, 1, 3).setValues(source1);
  sheetBase.getRange(sheetBase.getLastRow(), 7, 1, 3).setValues(source2);
  sheetBase.getRange(sheetBase.getLastRow(), 10, 1, 3).setValues(source3);
  sheetBase.getRange(sheetBase.getLastRow(), 13, 1, 3).setValues(source4);
```

Comment: The `sourceEqpt` variable is undefined. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.concat()`, `Array.flat()` and `Sheet.appendRow()`, like this:

```
  const data = sourceEqpt.concat(origem.getRange('E12:G15').getValues()).flat();
  sheetBase.appendRow(data);
```